# slime v.2014-04-27 sbcl v.1.2.0 lisp in-package does not change *package* after compilation and loading command C-c C-k

Tags: sbcl, slime

This is the code:

```
(defpackage :morse
  (:use :common-lisp))

(in-package :morse)
...
```

When I use C-c C-k (Compile/Load file):

```
CL-USER> *package*
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
; compiling file "/home/frederik/Lisp/Code/mycode/marco_baringer.lisp" (written 16 JUN 2014 11:30:15 AM):

; /home/frederik/Lisp/Code/mycode/marco_baringer.fasl written
; compilation finished in 0:00:00.025
CL-USER> *package*
#<PACKAGE "COMMON-LISP-USER">
CL-USER>
```

I am still in package "COMMON-LISP-USER" when the command "(in-package :morse)" is given in the source code. I should be in "MORSE" I think because when I give the command in the REPL:

```
...
CL-USER> (in-package :morse)
#<PACKAGE "MORSE">
MORSE> *package*
#<PACKAGE "MORSE">
MORSE> 
...
```

Any idea? Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From: Nick Levine  ravenbrook.com>
Subject: Re: SLIME compile and load file REPL stays at  "CL-USER"   with "(in-package :xyz)" in code and not "XYZ"
Newsgroups: gmane.lisp.slime.devel
Date: 2014-06-17 08:12:34 GMT (15 minutes ago)

> From: Frederik Cheeseman  evonet.be>
>   Date: Tue, 17 Jun 2014 07:54:20 +0000 (UTC)
>
> When I do C-c C-k (SLIME compile/load file) the REPL stays at
>   "CL-USER". Shouldn't it switch to "MORSE" because of the
>   "(in-package :morse)" code line?

No (and this applies to CL in general, not just to SLIME). This is
because, according to the spec, "load binds *readtable* and *package*
to the values they held before loading the file." In effect:

```
(defun load (file &key ...)
  (let ((*package* *package*))
    (in-load file ...)))
```

- n